# WPF Apps running within WPF Apps

Tags: c#, wpf, shell, window-managers

I would like to run a shell window manager kiosk-style WPF app that is full screen and contains in it other WPF apps.

Each WPF app is a project of it's own in my VS solution, what are the best practices for loading an instance of the other apps into my shell app and (preferably) confine them to certain bounds within the window manager.

Comment: Please take a look at [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://mef.codeplex.com/).

Comment: My first question is: why not use WPF UserControls instead? They would seem to have all the properties that you are looking for....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to rethink your design.

Instead of trying to load "other WPF Applications", it would be far simpler to load Windows, or potentially even better, UserControls, from the other assemblies (projects/solutions) and display them directly within your Application.

Extensibility like this can be accomplished fairly easily via [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/), which is built into the framework.  This would allow you to define contracts that can be loaded dynamically in your main application, and used to build the functionality as needed.

Comment: You said better than I could, yea what I'm really wanting is to load other wpf windows (from other VS projects) into my app. I'll look into this framework.